# Can't backup my tablet

Tags: twrp, clockworkmod-recovery

I tried to Backup my tablet with both **CWM** and **TWRP** but didn't success to get it backed-up,

**in CWM :**
the tablet stuck in the step of "generating backup boot imgae"

**in TWRP :**
the tablet fails in backup and gives me the following messages in log:

```
Updating partition details...
E :Unable to mount '/emmc'
E :Unable to mount '/emmc'
E :Unable to mount Storage.
E :Unable to mount '/emmc'
```

and worth to mention that in **TWRP** it Reads *the tablet Storage* as **0MB** either with **Internal SD Card** or with **External SD Card** , in addition to it doesn't allow me to choose either of them while configuring any settings in it.

**Hint:** I'm using *Lenovo Idea Tab A3000-H*

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @DanHulme my question is: How to overcome one of these two issues?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that both recovery images you were using were designed specifically for your device model?

Comment: @Chahk I think So, as I tried some wrong recovery images at first and it wasn't even boot, but I get these images after my search for a recovery specially for my device.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat are you sure the tablet wasn't encrypted?

Comment: @Chahk I think it wasn't besides I already reset it once and format the sdcard once